# Which unit of measurement does the Paint.setTextSize(float) use?

Tags: android, units-of-measurement

I want to draw text with an specific height(in pixels) on a view using `Canvas`. Can you simply use `Paint.setTextSize(float)` with the number of pixels or is this using `dp` or `sp`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It uses pixels, but you can convert it to dp using this code:

```
double getDPFromPixels(double pixels) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    switch(metrics.densityDpi){
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                pixels = pixels * 0.75;
                break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                 //pixels = pixels * 1;
                 break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                 pixels = pixels * 1.5;
                 break;
    }
    return pixels;
}
```

Comment: @Todd Davies - how do i use this inside a custom View class? Can't use getWindowManager()

Comment: @Neil - You can use View's method `getContext()` to obtain the `Context`, after that you can call `Context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)` to obtain `WindowManager`. More on this here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html.

Comment: By the way, the answer is incorrect, `dp` is `px/density`. Actually it can be simplified replacing `switch` with `pixels /= metrics.density`.

Comment: @Tzoiker could you please elaborate? Didn't get what I should change.

Comment: @m iav, replace the whole `switch` with `pixels /= metrics.density`.

Comment: your function returns double, but it should be float

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to get a px value for such methods is to simply define the appropriate dp or sp value in the dimens.xml file and retrieve it like this:

```
int sizeInPx = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.sizeInSp);
```

You actually have 3 methods available to use depending on your needs:

- `getDimension()` Returns a float in pixels.
- `getDimensionPixelSize()` Returns an int in pixels. This is the same as getDimension(), except the returned value is ROUNDED to the nearest integer value and it ensures that a non-zero input value results in a non zero output value (eg 0.1 is returned as 1, not 0).
- `getDimensionPixelOffset()` Returns an int in pixels. This is the same as getDimension(), except the returned value is TRUNCATED (ie. rounded down). The result may be zero.

Comment: This is the best answer; it works correctly on all existing devices AND will continue to work on future devices (Todd Davies answer is missing the newer densities such as xhdpi, xxhdpi and so on).  This is also more flexible you can provide an alternative dimens.xml file for different screen sizes (tablets, etc.) or change between dp and sp as necessary.

Comment: Yes, this TheIT's answer is the best answer as  WanderingLinguist says, because Todd Davies's solution should be updated to include also xHigh, xxhigh and xxxhigh and tv cases ans what ever cases come in future showing that its complicated and will be broken easily, instead of TheIT's answer which will work now and in future even if  what ever devices will come and solution works as Android is planned to handle all king device density.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work as intended: A `22sp` text looks good on a big screen (e.g. Pixel XL - 1440x2560, 560dpi) but on a small one (e.g. Nexus One - 480x800 hdpi=240dpi) it's not even readable. With e.g. `myPaint.setTextSize(80)` the text looks good on both screens and is also about the same size (there's always some type of difference in terms of size with different devices, even though it's usually really small).

Comment: @neph I saw you asking the same question on another answer, the only thing I can think of is that the canvas / bitmap you're drawing on is being scaled, because the setTextSize() method takes in pixel units, so a value of 80 should look massive on a Nexus One. Good luck!

Comment: @TheIT Yes, I posted infos about this on multiple questions. And also yes, the image is bigger than the canvas would be on a small device (about 2k x 2k). I read on a different question that a canvas scales automatically (according to dpi,...) if you give it the text size directly (instead of using `R.dimen.textSize`) and that's the only thing that actually worked - none of the other suggestions for computing the text size did.

Comment: @Neph, the canvas definitely doesn't scale automatically - I suspect what's happening is you're creating a canvas of a fixed size (eg 2kx2k), then rendering a font of a fixed size (80), then displaying this canvas on a view which is scaling the canvas to fit into a size that's relative to the screen space (eg 50% of the screen, or match_parent). The correct approach is to create with a canvas that's sized depending on the screen DPI (eg for hdpi devies it might be 512x512), which will then require a text size dependent on the DPI.

Comment: @TheIT I create a canvas using a bitmap from an image that's downloaded at runtime. The image is e.g. 2k x 2k (not my image, so can't change that) and so is the canvas. I also use that same bitmap in a `PhotoView` (Chris Bane's) to be able to zoom,... the image. I was accidently using a smaller canvas before but it then didn't draw stuff in the right spot. Thanks for the tip with the "correct approach", I'll try it when I have some time but for now I'm going to leave it like this because in the end it works on different devices, which I wanted. ;)

Answer (score 1):

These methods include `DisplayMetrics` that can be added into future Android SDK.

Pixels to dip:

```
public static float getDipFromPixels(float px) {
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                px,
                Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics()
        );
}
```

Dip to pixels:

```
public static float getPixelsFromDip(float dip) {
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
                dip,
                Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics()
        );
}
```