# Is it possible to set the text size by pixels, instead of dpi?

Tags: android

The text I draw seems to be about the same size on a 10 inch screen and a 7 inch screen, thus it is not always lined up with the background, which is a bitmap.  Is there a way to set the text size in pixcles

This is the code I have now

```
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);  
paint.setTextSize(20); 
canvas.drawText("SETTINGS:", tx,ty, paint);
```

Comment: The unit is pixels already. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720093/which-unit-of-measurement-does-the-paint-settextsizefloat-use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);  
paint.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
canvas.drawText("SETTINGS:", tx,ty, paint);
```

Read more abaoute [TypedValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html)

Att: The source is on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494037/how-to-set-text-size-of-textview-dynamically-for-diffrent-screens) post.

Hope it helps ^^

Comment: Paint.setTextSize no such method with TypedValue. Use TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12f, resources.displayMetrics)